# reverse animation of Image Sequence?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a button and I would like to give it some animation. Everything works fine, but I am trying to figure out a way to reverse the animation's image sequence order so that the button would seem to restore it's previous state. I can't find anything in the docs, and it seems like it may not be possible to reverse the image sequence? 
If it's not possible to reverse the order, how can I give the button a different image sequence? should I reefed it with a new array?

da code:

```
 animatedButton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:animButtonRect];
[animatedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"messaging_00014.png"]];
[animatedButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

animatedButton.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00000.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00001.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00002.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00003.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00004.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00005.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00006.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00007.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00008.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00009.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00010.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00011.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00012.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00013.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00014.png"],
 nil];

 animatedButton.animationDuration = 1.0;
 animatedButton.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.view addSubview:animatedButton];
```

Comment: Can't you just supply it with an array that has those images in the reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply is a little late but I have been working on reverse animations and thought Id share a nice little piece of code.

Note: This code is for an animation sequence of 30 images with the image names being 4 digits long. eg. image_0001.jpg

```
-(void)animation
{
 NSMutableArray *animationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int animationSizeTwo = 30;

    for (int i=0; i< animationSizeTwo; i++) {

        NSString *zeros = @"000";

        if ( i >= 1000 ) {

            zeros = @"";

        }
        else if ( i >= 100 ) {

            zeros = @"0";

        }
        else if ( i >= 10 ) {

            zeros = @"00";
        }
        NSString *animationNameTwo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(name)"];

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%d.jpg", animationNameTwo, zeros, i];

        [animationArrayTwo addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];


    }


    _imageView.animationImages = animationArrayTwo;
    _imageView.animationDuration = 1;
    _imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    _imageView.image = [_imageView.animationImages lastObject];
    [_imageView startAnimating];
}
```

Then to reverse the animation your simply use this bit of code inplace of the image count:

int animationSizeTwo = 0;

```
    for (int i=30; i> animationSizeTwo; i--) {
```

As I said it might be too late to answer your question but could always come in handy in the future,
Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but since it was never answered here is a solution. Just place the same images in reverse and skip the first and last in the sequence.

```
animatedButton.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00000.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00001.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00002.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00003.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00004.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00005.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00006.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00007.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00008.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00009.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00010.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00011.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00012.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00013.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00014.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00013.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00012.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00011.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00010.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00009.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00008.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00007.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00006.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00005.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00004.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00003.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00002.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"mov_00001.png"],
 nil];
```